# Django - 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a form which allows `user` (extended OneToOne by `UserProfile`) to became a `translator`. This means that if the `User` is logged-in, he/she can click on `Become a Translator` button which redirects them to pre-filled form. This form should be pre-filled if there is not null such attribute in `UserProfile`.

So if somebody has already filled his last_name, the last name should be prefilled in this form, otherwise, he has to fill it because for Translator it's required.

So I've tried to put user.userprofile argument as an attribute of the form class but it raises:

```
 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Could you give me some hint?

```
@login_required
def register_as_translator(request):
    register_as_translator_form = TranslatorRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if register_as_translator_form.is_valid():
            pass
    register_as_translator_form = TranslatorRegistrationForm(request.user.userprofile)
    context = {
        'register_as_translator_form':register_as_translator_form,
    }
    return render(request,'auth/registration/register-translator.html',context=context)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('married', 'Married'),
        ('separated', 'Separated'),
        ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widowed', 'Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
        ('coincidence', u'It was coincidence'),
        ('relative_or_friends', 'From my relatives or friends'),
    )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True,
                                                blank=True)

    # TRANSLATOR ATTRIBUTES

    is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    language_tuples = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageTuple)

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    number_of_ratings = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

EDIT:
TRACEBACK:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register-as-translator

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templates\bootstrap\uni_form.html, error at line 1
   'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'   1 :  {% load crispy_forms_utils %}
    2 : 
   3 : {% specialspaceless %}
   4 :     {% if include_media %}{{ form.media }}{% endif %}
   5 :     {% if form_show_errors %}
   6 :         {% include "bootstrap/errors.html" %}
   7 :     {% endif %}
   8 :     {% for field in form %}
   9 :         {% include "bootstrap/field.html" %}
   10 :     {% endfor %}
   11 : {% endspecialspaceless %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\SolutionsForLanguagesApp\views.py" in register_as_translator
  32.     return render(request,'auth/registration/register-translator.html',context=context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1043.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  736.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_filters.py" in as_crispy_form
  70.     return template.render(c)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_utils.py" in render
  27.         return remove_spaces(self.nodelist.render(context).strip())

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  209.                 return template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  319.                     match = condition.eval(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in eval
  951.         return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  709.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  850.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  913.                             current = current()

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in non_field_errors
  289.         return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  362.         self._clean_fields()

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_fields
  374.                 value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))

File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  231.         return data.get(name)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register-as-translator
Exception Value: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `request.user.userprofile` as a positional argument to `TranslatorRegistrationForm` in this line:

```
register_as_translator_form = TranslatorRegistrationForm(request.user.userprofile)
```

You should pass it as a keyword argument because Django forms expect `data` (POST/GET) as the first positional argument.

If your form accepts userprofile keyword argument in the `__init__` method, you should pass it as a keyword argument instead. Like this:

```
register_as_translator_form = TranslatorRegistrationForm(user=request.user.userprofile)
```

---

If you want to pass initial data to the form, you can pass it using `initial` keyword argument instead.

```
initial_data = {'name': 'John'}
register_as_translator_form = TranslatorRegistrationForm(initial=initial_data)
```

**Note**: Initial data keys must match your form fields.

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'... I know where is probably the problem. The problem is that userprofile has for example only IBAN attribute which I want to be prefilled, on the other hand user has for example last_name which I want to be prefilled to. So it is trying to get name from userprofile, not user.... I suppose.

Comment: If you want to pass initial data to the form, see updated answer. Otherwise you should put your forms.py code in the question too.